# Jersey client unmarshall JSON include root element error

Tags: java, json, jersey-client

I'm connecting to a remote server which I do not have control over.
The JSON that is send back includes a root element.

```
{"company":{"name":"Personal"}}
```

When trying to unmarshall the string into a company object I get the following error: `org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "company"`

Below is my configuration in my test class. I'm using JUnit 4.12, Jersey-client 1.19 and Jersey-json 1.19

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Company{

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company{" + "name=" + name + '}';
    }
}
```

The test client:

```
public class CompanyResourceTest {

    @Test
    public void createClient() {    

        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);


        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8686/voucher-test/rest/company");

        String companyName = "Personal";
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, companyName );
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus() + ", " + response.getStatusInfo());
        }

        Company json = response.getEntity(Company.class);
    }
}
```

What can I do to unmarshall the JSON string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Wrapper class that will have the Company object as a property. e.g.,

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CompanyResponse{
  private String company;

  public String getCompany() {
    return company;
  }

  public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company= company;
  }
}
```

Then, use this class to get the response from the server.
i.e., change the following

```
Company json = response.getEntity(Company.class);
```

to

```
Company json = response.getEntity(CompanyResponse.class).getCompany();
```

UPDATE

As suggested by @JuanDM, including the `name` attribute in the `@XmlRootElement` also works:
`@XmlRootElement(name="company")`

Comment: Isn't there a cleaner way in Jersey to accomplish that?

Comment: @JuanDM Do you mean without creating a response class?

Comment: @Priyesh yes, i can't understand why create that "wrapper" instead of put the name in `@XmlRootElement(name = "company")` works.

Comment: @Priyesh, I tried and actually works, but i was wondering why the need to do so, i think it is boilerplate

Comment: @JuanDM You can perhaps add it as another answer.

Comment: @Priyesh I asked because i can't find another answer haha

Answer (score 0):

You need and default(empty) constructor in your Company class

Comment: The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors